# E: Unable to locate package php5-imap

Tags: apt, php, imap

I am trying to install PHP imap on Ubuntu Server 16.

Following the steps on: [php5-imap on Ubuntu 14.04 is not enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484921/php5-imap-on-ubunut-14-04-is-not-enabled)

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-imap

E: Unable to locate package php5-imap
```

Comment: I have the issue when trying to install cURL:
sudo apt-get install php5-curl

E: Unable to locate package php5-curl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You receive the error because `php5` is outdated.

Execute : `sudo apt-get install php7.0-imap`

Comment: If you desperately need php 5, you can use this ppa : `ppa:ondrej/php`

Comment: Thanks a lot! but what's the alternative of sudo php5enmod imap
 because when I replace it by sudo php7enmod imap
it says command not found

Comment: alternative of `php5enmod` == `phpenmod`

Comment: If you desperately need php 5, try  `sudo apt-get install php5.6-intl`

Answer (score 3):

I had to downgrade from PHP 7 to PHP 5.6, so I was following:
[How can I downgrade from PHP 7 to PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04)

and applying general "naming convention" from that article I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6-curl
```

and it worked for me.
PS don't forget to run:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

afterwards.