# Install php imap on ubuntu 16.04 with php5.6

Tags: php, email, imap

I installed php5.6 from the  repository ppa:ondrej/php but I need to send emails using smtp or imap...

I know that if you are doing to install that in the default version of php that comes with Ubuntu 14.06 you could use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap
sudo php5enmod imap
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But I'm using ubuntu 16.04, with php5.6.. And I cant find how to enable it.. 
I installed using

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap
```

But still is not working... I have to enable it? I think it should be something like:

```
sudo php5.6enmod imap
```

but I cant figure out how...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post seems to have the answer:
[E: Unable to locate package php5-imap](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769250/e-unable-to-locate-package-php5-imap)

Looks like you need to follow the naming convention with 5.6 in it:

```
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6-imap
```

Then don't forget to restart apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Hope that helps.